# No such method error while using GoogleApiClient

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3

When i run my app with this code

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                    this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

I'm getting a error on the `build()` method as

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No direct method <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Looper;ILcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzg;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$OnConnectionFailedListener;)V in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzk; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzk' appears in /data/app/vivid.myapplication-2/base.apk:classes11.dex)
```

When i went through other answers, They asked us to remove the `build()` method and implement `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` Callbacks!!!

But this didn't solve my error ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using enableAutoManagement, the connection callbacks will be taken care of (unless you wish to override them and perform something specific). You can either

- skip addConnectionCallbacks(this) in the Builder (recommended)
- Or define 'this' by implementing the ConnectionCallbacks interface methods.

*Please note that there is no use to 'remove the build() method' as you state in your question above.*

You can use the following code (for implementing the interface through the second case):

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                    this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (null != mGoogleApiClient) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}
}
```

Also remember to use the [latest google-play-services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split) version (10.2.4 at the time of writing), so that the related method is found.

In the build.gradle file, update if not already:

compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4"

Comment: Which method did you use?
It seems that the play services version you are using isn't the latest one, such that it is unable to find that particular overridden method of OnConnectionFailedListener. 
The latest version is 10.2.4
I have updated the answer, for that case.